# How to add an image to a navigation bar on a github website

Tags: html, css, github

I'm making a GitHub website and wish to add the websites logo as the background image. Currently the code is

```
body{
    <!--some other styling-->
    background-image: url(/geekoicon.png)
}
```

I have the image file uploaded to Github and it isn't in any folders however, if I got to my website nothing shows up. When I tried putting the image in folders and putting the new path a the little icon that replaces a non existent image popped up. Here is the Github project page if that helps https://github.com/Geeko/geeko.github.io

Comment: A warm welcome to SO @snakebite_382. I have added an answer below. Please let me know if I can be of more help.

Answer (score 1):

As the image is at the location `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Geeko/geeko.github.io/master/geekoIcon.png` your CSS would be like this:

```css
body{
    background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Geeko/geeko.github.io/master/geekoIcon.png)
}
```

Note that the way Github sites work you could also reference it using the shorter URL of `https://geeko.github.io/geekoIcon.png`

Comment: Thank you for this I can finally start adding pictures to my website!

Comment: Glad to help @snakebite_382. Feel free to accept the answer using the tick if you wish.